# BizTalk Performance

Tags: c#, biztalk

We have a simple Biztalk application where we get some notification from a system to our receive port and we send them to different system using the API provided by those systems using WCF-Webhttp static one way send ports. This works perfectly fine, But we observed that few system take more time to send response and hence many send port running instances will be running and Biztalk gets slow down since we get large number of notification.

Is there any way where we can make a logic to delay the processing  and send them through send port when load is reduced. Or is there any way to increase the performance for these kind of scenarios

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should find out is what the number of concurrent connections the API you are calling can handle, and then configure the `maxconnection` parameter as per [Optimizations for BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/general-biztalk-server-optimizations1).  If there isn't a default `maxconnection` parameter set in the BTSConfig then the default is 2, which might be causing your  backlog.

If the other system is limited to only a few connections and can't handle the throughput, then you would need the throttle the rate at which you process the notifications.  Either by slowing the ingestion (rate of polling etc.), or if you can't control how fast the notifications come, then by inserting the notifications into a table, where you can then can control how fast you process them from there to even out the peak loads.

Another trick that sometimes works is to set the send port onto ordered delivery, which will mean it will process one at a time.  This works in scenarios where the receiving systems cannot handle multiple connections.

Comment: You mentioned about storing the notification in table and processing later, Can we use Azure Event Hub and load from event hub as required. Any thoughts\experience on this.

Comment: @techresearch  I haven't tried that, but if you are using BizTalk 2020 or BizTalk 2016 with Feature Pack 2 or above that should be possible.  If you are using Azure anyway, can't you do all the processing there?  Is there a reason you need to use BizTalk?